# "npm start" doesn't work on any react-js project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack

[[package.json]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aof8g.png)
i tried everything i tried to update npm, node, webpack also.

this is what i do: 
**npx create-react-app testapp**

**cd testapp**

**npm start or yarn start**

give me this:

OUTPUT:

There might be a problem with the project dependency tree.
It is likely not a bug in Create React App, but something you need to fix locally.

The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:

"webpack": "4.39.1"

Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it automatically.
However, a different version of webpack was detected higher up in the tree:

C:\node_modules\webpack (version: 4.38.0)

Manually installing incompatible versions is known to cause hard-to-debug issues.

If you would prefer to ignore this check, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
That will permanently disable this message but you might encounter other issues.

npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! client@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the client@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

Comment: post your package.json. at least the *scripts* pat of it

Comment: try npm install. It will install all the dependencies of the project.

Comment: I tried npm install and i tried to delete package.json then npm install i tried to even make a while new project

Comment: post your package.json

Comment: delete `C:\node_modules\ `

Comment: `$> SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true && yarn start`

Comment: i have done that already check again

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly how to put SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true

Comment: try npm install --save react react-dom react-scripts

Comment: @AliaksandrPitkevich i tried this btw and it didn't work

Comment: That will permanently disable this message but you might encounter other issues.

Comment: I thought that too at first but actually i didn't face any problem related to this issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks a lot for all but after many tries i created a .env file then i put this into it 
**SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true**
then yarn start or npm start and it worked

@MedetTleukabiluly who told me in comments thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Rather than adding `SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true` to .env file in your project, I would suggest using `Yarn`

Answer (score 0):

#### I had countered the same case, I solved via this link

If you've previously installed `create-react-app` globally via `npm install -g create-react-app`, we recommend you uninstall the package using `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` to ensure that **npx** always uses the latest version```

[https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started]